# How to display a different number of posts on Wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have set 10 posts to display per page from WordPress admin panel, but I want to dispaly 11 posts on first page and in my case its homepage. So I want to display 11 posts on homepage and for all other pages I want to display 10 posts.

I am trying to achieve it with this code but is_home() always return true regardless of page number.

```
function home_custom_query( $query ) {

    if (  is_home() )
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 11; 
    }

    return $query; 
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'home_custom_query' );
```

But above code change the number of posts for all pages including homepage.

I also tried this to detect page number and tried as below

```
function home_custom_query( $query ) {

    if (  is_home() && $query->query_vars['paged'] == 0)
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 11; 
    }

    return $query; 
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'home_custom_query' );
```

it changes posts per page to 11 for homepage but displays nothing on all other pages.

I also tried the [cbnet-different-posts-per-page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cbnet-different-posts-per-page/) plugin which fulfills the purpose but it add some extra functionality which I don't want to use. I need a simple solution for my problem. And I am sure there will be a neat and clean way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as follows, might be helpful for you as well.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$page_num = $paged;
if( $paged >1 ) 
    $showposts = 10; 
else 
    $showposts = 11;
query_posts('showposts=' .$showposts. '&paged='.$page_num);
?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
       // WordPress loop
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template must have a loop somewhere, you can do a query post in it. You van give the parameters showposts in it. Her a example.

```
<?php
$page_num = $paged;
if ($pagenum='') $pagenum =1;

if(is_home) { $showposts = 11 } else { $showposts = 10 }

query_posts('showposts=' .$showposts. '&paged='.$page_num); 
?>



<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
       // WordPress loop
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```